# Documents for AU Visitor visa (subclass 600) Business Visitor stream

Tags: visas, paperwork, australia, business-travel

I am a citizen of the Russian Federation. Currently, I work and have my family in Germany (permanent residency). I was invited by a possible future employer (a university) for a job interview in Australia. As far as I understand, I need to apply for a Visitor visa (subclass 600) Business Visitor stream. The possible future employer provides a letter of invitation and covers my travel expenses.

1. The [supporting documents guide of the Department of Home Affairs](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/business-visitor-stream#HowTo) states that I need to provide "a letter from my employer stating they expect me to return to my job" (as a proof to show I am visiting Australia as a temporary visitor only). My current employer will not give me any letter for the purpose of a job interview (it doesn't make any sense). Will my current job contract (the main page where the dates of the contract and the salary are clearly stated) be enough to provide?
2. Do I need to provide personal bank statements if my salary is clearly stated, and my possible future employer covers my travel expenses? If so, for which period (I can not find this information on the website of the Department of Home Affairs)?

Thank you.

Comment: For your first question: Are you taking time off work to attend the interview? That would typically require approval from your employer, and they should be able to write a letter confirming that they are aware of your travel and your employment will continue afterwards. They don't need to know that you're going *for an interview*.

Comment: For your second question, while [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) is for the UK, it is still relevant for Australian visa applications.

Comment: @ChrisH yes, of course. In this case, a separate document from our HR department is provided where the vacation time is clearly stated. The problem with the letter is that we get such kind of documents directly from the head of the department, and our department is very small, so the head of the department will 99.99% ask me about the reason why the letter is required.

Comment: @colombien if the department head asks why you need the letter, the answer is "I need a visa for the trip, and I need the letter for my visa application". If they start asking more details about the trip you might have to be a little vague or just tell them it's a private matter, but your work situation doesn't sound too dissimilar to mine and I suspect you're overthinking this.